# What's the Deal with the "Hint" Tag in system.xml?

Tags: adminhtml, system.xml

I've found opaque reference to a `<hint/>` tag in `system.xml` files.  What's the deal with this tag?  Is its use documented anywhere?

Comment: Have you got an example. I could not find one in Mage 1.8 or 1.9

Comment: @DavidManners See below — this was a more a "I want to document Magento" question in response to a question someone tweeted me than a "I have a problem" question.  Other people's knowledge and context is more than welcome though.

Comment: Ah I get you. Though do any modules actually use it or it hidden away?

Comment: @DavidManners It's hidden away, and the way the system configuration HTML is setup it doesn't even work.  I **think** the hint feature of the field rendering might work on other forms (product editing, etc), but that's not driven by system.xml.  Also relevant, Marius's module creator has its own help/hint feature. http://alanstorm.com/magento_ultimate_module_creator_review

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm not sure about EE, but in CE this is a vestigial tag from a never completed help system. The intent appears to have been to give each form field in the System configuration section a small "hint", or help text.

The help text is added when the field element is created

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php
$hint  = (string)$element->hint ? Mage::helper($helperName)->__((string)$element->hint) : '';

//...

$field = $fieldset->addField($id, $fieldType, array(
    'name'                  => $name,
    'label'                 => $label,
    'comment'               => $comment,
    'tooltip'               => $tooltip,
    'hint'                  => $hint,
    'value'                 => $data,
    'inherit'               => $inherit,
    'class'                 => $element->frontend_class . $sharedClass . $requiresClass,
    'field_config'          => $element,
    'scope'                 => $this->getScope(),
    'scope_id'              => $this->getScopeId(),
    'scope_label'           => $this->getScopeLabel($element),
    'can_use_default_value' => $this->canUseDefaultValue((int)$element->show_in_default),
    'can_use_website_value' => $this->canUseWebsiteValue((int)$element->show_in_website),
));
```

That first line reads the value of a `<hint/>` in `system.xml`.

Next, when Magento renders the field as HTML, the last thing it does is add the hint in a nested div.

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form/Field.php
$html.= '<td class="">';
if ($element->getHint()) {
    $html.= '<div class="hint" >';
    $html.= '<div style="display: none;">' . $element->getHint() . '</div>';
    $html.= '</div>';
}
$html.= '</td>';
```

Finally, there's a small bit of javascript that's called on an admin page load.

```
#File: app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/system/config/js.phtml
function showHint() {    
    $$('.hint').each(function(element){
        Event.observe(element, 'mouseover', function(){            
            element.down().show()
        });
        Event.observe(element, 'mouseout', function(){
            element.down().hide()
        });
    });
}
```

This javascript sets up event handlers such that mousing in or out of the help text will make it appear.  The intent being this "hint" would help users understand what each field does.

The problem?  The HTML/CSS on the backend makes the hint `td` a single pixel wide.  This prevents anyone mousing over the hint to view it.  Try adding a hint to your field configuration and then running the following from your browser's javascript console

```
$$('.hint').each(function(el){
    el.down().show();
});
```

You'll see something like this.

[image]

(the *This is a hint* text).

I've always chalked this up as one of those "Best Laid Plans" thing that got dropped once Magento launched.

Comment: Beautiful bit of Magento archeology - love it!

Comment: Impressed with this, I am.

Comment: Note that you can [override the Magento admin theme](http://www.techawaken.com/creating-a-new-magento-admin-theme/) to show hints by default. I've also modified it to change textbox font to Consolas for better legibility, etc.